# Fancy generics capture collision

Tags: java, generics

Please give me a hint as to what is going on here:

```
List<? extends Number> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<? extends Number> b = new ArrayList<Number>();

a.addAll(b); // ouch! compiler yells at me, see the block below:
/*
  incompatible types
  found   : java.util.List<capture#714 of ? extends java.lang.Number>
  required: java.util.List<java.lang.Number>
 */
```

This simple code does not compile. I vaguely remember something related to type captures, like those should be mostly used in interface specs, not the actual code, but I never got dumbfounded like that.

This of course might be fixed brute-forcefully, like that:

```
List<? extends Number> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<? extends Number> b = new ArrayList<Number>();

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
List<Number> aPlain = (List<Number>) a;
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"}) 
List<Number> bPlain = (List<Number>) b;

aPlain.addAll(bPlain);
```

So, do I *really* have to either give up captures in the declaration (the capture came to me from an interface, so I'll have to change some API), or stick with type casts with suppression annotations (which generally suck and complicates code a bit)?

Comment: Hi, why not just declare `a` as `List<Number> a = new ArrayList<Number>()` ?

Comment: Well, I have some API which declares this capture already when returning a List to me. I use a constructor just to keep things simpler while making them a bit more obscure (unintetionally).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have essentially two lists of possibly different types. Because `? extends Number` means a class which extends `Number`. So for list `a` it can be `classA` and for list `b` it can be for example `classB`. They are not compatible, they can be totally different.

Comment: You're mean... providing a comment as a decoy. I wanted to reply to that comment before answering. Now the comment is gone and you answered instead. ;)

Comment: @musiKk - Hahahaha, everything was planned;)

Comment: This is somehow related to type covariance. Maybe the example itself (addAll operation) is somewhat restrictive, but my opinion is that I should be able to perform any collection operations as long as equals() and hashCode() are defined on the objects which are in the collection.

_UPD_: And, actually, Java is also restrictive in this regard: I am unable to create a wildcard directly:
    new ArrayList<? extends Number>(); // ouch!..

Comment: `...as long as equals() and hashCode() are defined on the objects which are in the collection ...` note that lists don't use those methods at all. Additionally, Generics are not only about collections and there's no distinction between different uses of those wildcards (as of which type of class is made generic or which type of collection you have) - at least yet.

Comment: `Java is also restrictive in this regard: I am unable to create a wildcard directly: new ArrayList<? extends Number>(); ` Why would you want to do that? All you need to know is that the ArrayList holds objects of type Number and thus `new ArrayList<Number>();` should be used. If you could use the `?` notation you'd still have to check the type of each element. And what would the `?` actually mean? - "You can put any object that is of type `Number` or a subclass into that list", which is exactly the same meaning as `new ArrayList<Number>();`.

Comment: Well, addAll() won't use equals(), while removeAll() would. I just was thinking of what operations we need to support to keep that List working. All your remarks are perfectly correct and helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that if you use `List<? extends Number>` you could actually do:

```
List<? extends Number> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> b = new ArrayList<Double>();

a.addAll(b); //ouch, would add Doubles to an Integer list
```

The compiler can't tell from `List<? extends Number>` what the actual type parameter is and thus won't let you do the add operation.

You also shouldn't cast the lists to `List<Number>` if you get them as a parameter, since you could actually have a list of Integer objects and add Double objects to it.

In that case you better create a new `List<Number>` and add the objects from both lists:

```
List<Number> c = new ArrayList<Number>(a.size() + b.size());
c.addAll(a);
c.addAll(b);
```

Edit: in case you create both lists locally, you would not neet the `?` wildcard anyway (since you'd always have `List<Number>`).

Comment: Uhm... the workaround code was not correct at all. The idea is that I get two lists with a capture, so I'd recoded that code to reflect the idea.

Comment: Deleted my comment on the "workaround" to prevent misinterpretation

Answer (score 5):

Don't use the `?` wildcard. It means "Some specific type I don't know", and since you don't know the type, you can't add anything to the list. Change your code to use `List<Number>` and everything will work.

This is fast becoming the most frequently asked Java question, in a hundred variations...

Comment: Okay, okay, but what are general guides to using wildcards at all?

Comment: @Anton: Look here for a deeper explanation with examples: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20is%20a%20wildcard?  But in general, wildcards are only useful in a few rare cases.

Answer (score 4):

PECS (producer-extends, consumer-super)

- You cannot put anything into a type declared with an EXTENDS wildcard
  except for the value null, which belongs to every reference type
- You cannot get anything out from a type declared with an SUPER
  wildcard    except for a value of type Object, which is a super type
  of every    reference type

Comment: For example this works:
`List<? super Number> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<? extends Number> b = new ArrayList<Number>();
a.addAll(b);`

Answer (score 1):

The thing is:

```
List<? extends Number> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<? extends Number> b = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

could also be read as:

```
List<x extends Number> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<y extends Number> b = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

How should the compiler know that x and y are the same?

Comment: Well, I was quite sure that compiler has all information it needs. Not the case... :)