# java template how to return function parameter class type instance with template type

Tags: java, templates

i have template class like this.Msg is the known type

```
class ResultSet<T extends Msg>
{
}
```

then in my app class i want to functionality like this.

```
class App
{
      public ResultSet<? extends Msg> getResult(Class<? extends Msg> cls)
     {
         return new ResultSet();
     }
}
```

i have message derived from Msg class
let's say

```
class HelloMsg extends Msg
{
  String greeting = null;
}
```

but i can't use the  getResult function

```
ResultSet<HelloMsg> rs = getResult(HelloMsg.class);
```

error is :
incompatible type : ResultSet ....

please correct the heading as needed.

Comment: Please post the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found the answer .

```
class App
{
      public <T extends Msg> ResultSet<T> getResult(Class<T> cls)
     {
         return new ResultSet();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this method signature:

```
public ResultSet<? extends Msg> getResult(Class<? extends Msg> cls)
```

There is no "connection" between the returned generic type and the parameter type, except the same parent class, because `?` is a wildcard. That is why the compiler mentioning incompatible types, since the returned type by a different type as provided as the argument. See this question for more information: [java generics : fancy capture collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857561/java-generics-fancy-capture-collision).

To fix that you could change you `App` class as follows:

```
class App<T extends Msg> {
     public ResultSet<T> getResult() { // no need for a method parameter anymore
         return new ResultSet<>(); // don't forget the diamond operator here
     }
}
```