# Java 8 Stream and generic interface in chain of responsibility pattern

Tags: spring, generics, java-8

In a Spring Boot application, running on Java 8, I want to implement a generic behavior to process different types of commands.

The code below illustrates the solution I had in mind.

A generic processor pattern

```
public interface Processor<C extends Command> {
    TypeCommand getCommandType();
    void processCommand(C command);
}

public abstract class AbstractProcessor<C extends Command> implements Processor<C> {
    @Override
    public void processCommand(C command) {
        // Some common stuff 
        // ...

        // Specific process
        Result result = executeCommand(command);

        // More common stuff
        // ...
    }

    protected abstract Result executeCommand(C command);
}

@Component
public AddCommandProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<AddCommand> {

    @Override
    protected Result executeCommand(AddCommand addCommand) {
        // Execute command
        // ...
        return result; 
    }

    @Override
    public TypeCommand getCommandType() {
        return TypeCommand.ADD_COMMAND;
    }
}
```

The command :

```
public abstract class Command {
    private final String uid;
    private final LocalDateTime creationDate;
    private final TypeCommand type;
    // Constructor and getters omited ...
}

public class AddCommand extends Command {
    private final Double amount;
    // Constructor and getters omited ...
}
```

The service with the chain of responsibility :

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final List<Processor<? extends Command>> processors;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(final List<Processor<? extends Command>> processors) {
        this.processors = processors;
    }

    public void processCommand(final Command command) {
        processors.stream()
            .filter(p -> command.getType() == p.getCommandType())
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(processor -> processor.processCommand(command));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not compile. The line :

```
.ifPresent(processor -> processor.processCommand(command));
```

failed to compiles with the message :

```
processCommand(capture <? extends Command>) in Processor cannot be applied to (Command)
```

I don't see any other way to do it as intended. Where am I wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Change the `private final List<Processor<? extends Command>> processors;` to `private final List<Processor<Command>> processors;` if you can  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857561/java-generics-fancy-capture-collision

Comment: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488)

Comment: Changing `private final List<Processor<? extends Command>> processors;` to `private final List<Processor<Command>> processors;` compiles, but then Spring will not inject the Processor's implementations into the collection :'(

Comment: @CrakBoom, you can configure the bean injection, then you wouldn't need the unsafe casting. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067356/1018903

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to drop the generics on `Processor<? extends Command> processor` into just `Processor processor` which will transform the error into a warning about raw types which you can mute with `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`

```
.ifPresent(processor -> ((Processor) processor).processCommand(command));
```

Another method is to make `processCommand` generic and upcast `Processor<? extends Command> processor` to the generic type, like this:

```
public <C extends Command> void processCommand(final C command) {
    processors.stream()
        .filter(p -> command.getType() == p.getCommandType())
        .findFirst()
        .map(processor -> (Processor<C>) processor)
        .ifPresent(processor -> processor.processCommand(command));
}
```

Which will give you a warning about an unchecked cast which you can mute with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Both of these methods will throw a `ClassCastException` if a `Command` that returns a specific `TypeCommand` isn't a subclass of the type that the (first) `Processor` that returns the same `TypeCommand` expects (e.g. if `SubCommand` returns `TypeCommand.ADD_COMMAND` but isn't a subclass of `AddCommand`).

Comment: Both methods work.  The `ClassCastException` is not a problem here, I have only one `Command` implementation by `TypeCommand` value.  Thanks !